# check unreachable code in most simple way in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, dead-code

I have a python code with is detect any errors in another python code saved in txt file, i did that i can detect magic numbers and more than 3 parameters in the function, and now i have to check un reachable code, but i don't have an idea how can i do it, i want to detect if there's a code after return in the function, i did several attempts and all of them failed

This main class :

```
class CodeAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.file_string = ""
        self.errors = {}
```

this is a method where it's pass detects function so i can print errors :

```
 def process_file(self):
        for i, line in enumerate(self.file):
            self.file_string += line
            self.check_divide_by_zero(i, line)
            self.check_parameters_num(i, line)
```

and for example this is check parameter function, i need to write similar one but to detect unreachable code :

```
  def check_parameters_num(self, i, line):
            count = line.count(",")
            if(line.startswith('def') and count+1 >= 3):
                self.errors.setdefault(i, []).append(('S007', ''))
```

Any one can help and have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you would have to use the `ast` module to look at the parse tree.

Look for:

- Conditions for `if` and `while` statements that are always `False`. (or always `true` in case of an `else`) This would involve "constant propagation", that is realizing that an expression that only depends on constants is itself constant.
- Code after a `return`, without that return being part of an `if`.
- Code at the end of a function that is indented incorrectly an thus in the module context.

Or you could look at how `mypy` is doing it.